# couldn't vs can't

Tags: modal-verbs

We normally say that the modal verb "**could**" is *less confident/more hesitant* than the modal verb "**can**". But what about the "**negative could**"; i,e, "**couldn't** or **could never**"?

Consider these sentences, please:

a) That **can't** be true.

b) That **couldn't** be true. (**not** talking about the past)

Which one of a) and b) is more confident?

c) I **can** never forget you.

d) I **could never** forget you. (**not** talking about the past)

Which one of c) and d) is more confident?

Comment: Why would putting it into the negative make any difference with respect to its relative certainty when compared to the other word?

Comment: Isn't d) a little more certain than c)?